# What should be bucket policy for a S3 that is owned by Coudfront OAI set but allow other AWS account to upload s3 objects

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have S3 that has restricted policy to serve private content. Only Cloudfront Origin Access Identity can access. But, other account should be allowed to upload new objects so that client can get new assets. What kind of policy should be set for this situation?

Currently my policy is like this

```
          {
                "Sid": "1",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": {
                    "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity SomeID12334"
                },
                "Action": "s3:GetObject",
                "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple statements in your bucket policy to handle the permissions.
Provide the role ARN from another account to provide the access to do specific actions on bucket.

```
     {
         "Sid": "1",
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Principal": {
             "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity SomeID12334"
            },
         "Action": "s3:GetObject",
         "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1570159952662",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<accountno>:role/rolename"
        },
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"
    }
```